# Jenkins project-based security

Tags: jenkins

In jenkins you can enable a project-based security matrix.
Unfortunatly I can't find any documentation the option *Credentials*.

[image]

The [documentation of the matrix based security](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix-based+security) describes these options:

- *Job*: Create, start, cancel a Job
- *Run*: Delete or update builds in build history
- *SCM*: Create tags in repository

But I've found no documentation for *Credentials*:

- Why should I manage Credentials per project? I thought it's a global configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I confirm it's to configure the global credentials, there is no credentials per project.

By checking the option "Enable project-based security", this will allow you to customize the permissions per job (but not the credentials).

I hope it help :)